# Javascript Form Input Retrieval

Tags: javascript, forms, alert

Why is it that in a form that contains a **Text Box** and a **Submit Button**, I can Alert what has been typed in the text box by the user, but can't print it on the page? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code

```
<form name="Serb" action="" method="get">
<input name="Name" type="text" size="15" maxlength="20" />
<input name="Join" type="submit" value="Join" onClick="serb(this.form)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function serb(form){
    var x = document.Serb.Name.value;   
    alert(x); \\this alerts
    document.write(x); \\this should print on page
    }
</script>
```

For some reason, the alert works fine and displays exactly what the user typed in the username box after pressing 'Join'. However, it won't print the information on the page. Why is that?

Comment: did you check the console for errors??

Comment: Nivas is right, check your comment, it begins with \\ instead of // Also, add ending tag for the form `</form>`

Answer (score 2):

It ***does* work**. The value in the textbox is printed on the page.

**BUT:**

1. `\\` do not mean anything in Javascript. Comments begin with `//`. This is most likely the reason why you are not seeing the value being written
2. `document.write` replaces whatever is in the HTML page with its argument. (If it is called after the document is loaded). So unless you are trying to learn Javascript this is not a very good idea.

   Actually it is not a very good idea to use it even when learning Javascript, unless you are trying to learn how `document.write` works.
   There are flexible (and better) ways to manipulate the content of a page, starting from the humble [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementById) to [complex DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use document.write() after the page has been loaded/parsed.  At that point, it will overwrite the page HTML with new content.  document.write() is generally used while the page is being loaded to insert content at a particular point into the page as it's being loaded.

If you want to put the value into some item on the page, then you need to use appropriate DOM methods for that, putting the value into an input field, setting the innerHTML on a div, etc...

You can read about document.write here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write.

Here's an example of fetching the value from the field and putting it in another object on the page without using document.write(): http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dU8Sr/.

HTML:

```
<form name="Serb" action="" method="get">
<input name="Name" type="text" size="15" maxlength="20" />
<input name="Join" type="button" value="Join" onClick="serb(this.form)" />
</form>
<br>
<br>Output: <span id="output"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
function serb(form) {
    var x = document.Serb.Name.value;   
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Calling *document.write* when the document is closed doesn't "add to the end of the page". It will first call *document.open()*, which completely clears the document of **all** content, so it replaces the content, not appends to it.